# Globally listen for Backbone.js Model.save

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'd like to append Backbone's native `Model.save()` method with a custom logging method that logs success and errors.  I know that on a per model basis I can call something like:

```
myModel.save().success(function() {
    // do something cool
});
```

But rather than adjusting every call to various models' save events, I'd like to simply listen for the save event on *any* model.  One way that I think I want to avoid is actually modifying the `Backbone.Model.prototype.save` method (although if someone has an elegant way to do this I'm open to it).

Any thoughts on how to create such an event listener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all your models/collections are using the default Backbone.sync method, you could create a new sync method to do the logging.

```
   var originalSync = Backbone.sync;
   var loggingSync = function(method, model, options) {
         // call original Backbone.sync
         var promise = originalSync(method, model, options);
         promise.done(function() {
            // if method is 'update' or 'create', log success
         });
         promise.fail(function() {
            // if method is 'update' or 'create', log failure
         });
         return promise;
      };
   Backbone.sync = loggingSync;
```

By default, Model.sync and Collection.sync both proxy through to Backbone.sync, so if you are using default sync, this change would take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var GlobalModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
save: function() {

}
});

myModel = GlobalModel.extend({
//..your model
})
```

Comment: This is definitely something that would work and I'm not ruling it out yet.  But rather than creating a custom model type, I'd really love a way to listen, without modifying existing models.  If there exists no way to do that, then I'm defintely going with this solution.  I just want to rule out the listener first.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is log AJAX success/failures, there's actually a much better way of doing it that doesn't even involve Backbone at all: `$.ajaxComplete`.

jQuery has this wonderful function called `ajaxComplete` that takes a function argument, and then runs that function every time a `$.ajax` call completes (failure or success).  By using this method (ie. "binding an event handler to the ajaxComplete pseudo-event") you:

A) don't have to muck with Backbone internals

B) are guaranteed to catch EVERY AJAX request (even those made without Backbone)

C) keep this logging code completely separate from the rest of your code

There's probably some other upsides I'm missing, but you get the idea.

If on the other hand you truly do care only about `save` and not just about AJAX requests, then ... well you could still use `$.ajaxComplete` and just do some filtering inside it to ignore non-saves.  But you could also make your own Model base class (as @salexch suggested) or worse you *could* muck with Backbone's internals, eg. by replacing `Backbone.Model.prototype.save` or `Backbone.sync` (as @Paul Hoenecke suggested), but then you're setting yourself up for trouble with future Backbone upgrades or 3rd party Backbone libraries you might want to use.

If you're interested, here's the doc page for `ajaxComplete`:
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Oh, and there's also some similarly named `$.ajaxSomething` methods (eg. `ajaxError`) for targeting only failures/successes/request starts/etc.

Comment: Not breaking future Backbone upgrades is really compelling to me.  I'm actually already using the $.ajaxComplete method - but the problem is that I'm making quite a few other ajax events that I have no interest in capturing.  I'm intrigued by the idea of filtering out non-backbone-save ajax events.  Do you have any thoughts on how you could filter these?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, if you follow @Paul Hoenecke's answer it's very unlikely that replacing `Backbone.sync` will break anything in the future (for it to break something Backbone would pretty much have to stop returning the XHR object from its sync method). However, if you want to go with `$.ajaxComplete` for the other reasons I listed, a simple way to filter would be to check the url of the XHR object that gets passed to your `$.ajaxComplete` handler.  (assuming your Backbone AJAX code and your non-Backbone AJAX code use different URLS).